# GoogleMaps android app with GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog()

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

So in the documentation here

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

it says to check the status of play services with `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()` and then display the error dialog if it's not okay.

This seems to be working fine for me, the dialog showing it's not installed with a button that opens up the play store all seems okay. My question is specifically about the returned results in `onActivityResult()`.

We have to pass a `requestCode` to `getErrorDialog()` and I get that back in `onActivityResult` just fine, but im more concerned with the `resultCode` returned. So far with all my testing I've gotten 0 (`RESULT_CANCELLED`). I was wondering if there was any way to know if the play services were installed successfully?

For now I'm handling it by just assuming that `RESULT_CANCELLED` means that they at least got to the play store and started downloading, and display another dialog that says "please restart this app once the play services complete installation" followed by a `finish()`.

Is this the best way to handle it? or is there a case that I'm missing where it will return `RESULT_OK` and I can just continue onward with my app working without restarting it?

Answer (score 1):

I must say that today I tried it, and I never got onActivityResult() called.

When dialog is cancelled, my OnCancelListener (getErrorDialog() parameter) is called, and when returning from PlayStore, whether installing Google Play Services or not, my app is destroyed.

Even more, when installing Google Play Services, onDestroy() is called when installation starts.

I think maybe this is an updated behaviour, and I think is consequent, because you can return from Play Store before background installation ends.

Nonetheless, I found a couple of links with sample code that may confirm in case onActivityResult() is called with RESULT_OK, it means that you can continue:

http://developer.android.com/training/location/activity-recognition.html

http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Hope it helps

Comment: that's weird that u dont get onActivityResult for sure, but thanks for the input anyway

Comment: I'm using Google Play Services rev 12, lib version 3.2.65 (834000-30),  the most updated today 2013/10/10 I think